# add close button to ajax fancybox

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup, fancybox, modal-dialog

I am using fancy box 1.3 with ajax option.
I want to add close button to popup which will act same as close image on the popup corner so
 written on click event of close button -

```
$.fn.fancybox.close()
```

tried with

```
`jQuery.fn.fancybox.close()`
```

none seem to work. I am getting jQuery.fn.fancybox.close() not function error message.
 here is code.

```
$('#cancel-filters-btn').click(function(){
            jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
});
```

Comment: regarding the answers so far, it seems pretty obvious :-D

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this

```
$('#cancel-filters-btn').click(function(){
            $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Comment: used above option it is giving error TypeError: wrap is undefined (926 out of range 4)

Comment: you just try with parent.$.fancybox.close();

Answer (score 2):

try delegating the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancel-filters-btn', function(){
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

please check this one

```
$('#cancel-filters-btn').click(function(){
           $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Comment: used above option it is giving error
TypeError: wrap is undefined


(926 out of range 4)

Answer (score 1):

You tried to call the function on no object.
Call it on your elements (by selector):

```
$('#cancel-filters-btn').click(function(){
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Comment: used above option it is giving error TypeError: wrap is undefined (926 out of range 4)